# Export data from mixpanel to Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, urllib, mixpanel

I am trying multiple ways to export data from mix panel to pandas. But I am unable to export in Step1 with API response.

```
import base64
import urllib.request
import ssl

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

class Mixpanel(object):

    ENDPOINT = 'https://mixpanel.com/api'
    DATA_ENDPOINT = 'http://data.mixpanel.com/api'
    VERSION = '2.0'

    def __init__(self, api_secret):
        self.api_secret = api_secret

    def request(self, methods, params, http_method='GET', format='json'):
        """
            methods - List of methods to be joined, e.g. ['events', 'properties', 'values']
                      will give us http://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/events/properties/values/
            params - Extra parameters associated with method
        """
        params['format'] = format
        # print(base64.b64encode(self.api_secret).decode("ascii"))

        request_url = '/'.join([self.ENDPOINT, str(self.VERSION)] + methods)
        
        if http_method == 'GET':
            data = None
            request_url = request_url + '/?' + self.unicode_urlencode(params)
        else:
            data = self.unicode_urlencode(params)

        auth = base64.b64encode(self.api_secret).decode("ascii")
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic {encoded_secret}'.format(encoded_secret=auth)}

        request = urllib.request.Request(request_url, data, headers)
        # print(request)
        context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request, context=context, timeout=120)
        str_response = response.read().decode('utf8')
        lines = str_response.splitlines(True)
        records = []
        for line in lines:
            obj = json.loads(line)
            records.append(obj)
        return records

    def unicode_urlencode(self, params):
        """
            Convert lists to JSON encoded strings, and correctly handle any
            unicode URL parameters.
        """
        if isinstance(params, dict):
            params = list(params.items())
        for i,param in enumerate(params):
            if isinstance(param[1], list):
                params.remove(param)
                params.append ((param[0], json.dumps(param[1]),))

        return urllib.parse.urlencode(
            [(k, v) for k, v in params]
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    encoded_secret = b'my_secret'
    # byteAPISecret = bytes(encoded_secret + ':', "utf-8")
    api = Mixpanel(api_secret=encoded_secret)
    data = api.request(['events'], {
        'event': ['sample event'],
        'unit': 'hour',
        'interval': 24,
        'type': 'general'
    })


    print(data)
    
    data_iter = api.request(['export'], {
        'event': ['sample event'],
        'to_date': "2022-02-16",
        'from_date': "2022-02-16"
    })

    print(data_iter)
```

it is printing for data like

```
[{'data': {'series': ['2022-02-20 19:00:00', '2022-02-20 20:00:00', '2022-02-20 21:00:00', '2022-02-20 22:00:00', '2022-02-20 23:00:00', '2022-02-21 00:00:00', '2022-02-21 01:00:00', '2022-02-21 02:00:00', '2022-02-21 03:00:00', '2022-02-21 04:00:00', '2022-02-21 05:00:00', '2022-02-21 06:00:00', '2022-02-21 07:00:00', '2022-02-21 08:00:00', '2022-02-21 09:00:00', '2022-02-21 10:00:00', '2022-02-21 11:00:00', '2022-02-21 12:00:00', '2022-02-21 13:00:00', '2022-02-21 14:00:00', '2022-02-21 15:00:00', '2022-02-21 16:00:00', '2022-02-21 17:00:00', '2022-02-21 18:00:00', '2022-02-21 19:00:00', '2022-02-21 20:00:00'], 'values': {'Course Content Start': {'2022-02-20 00:00:00': 79, '2022-02-20 01:00:00': 52, '2022-02-20 02:00:00': 69, '2022-02-20 03:00:00': 101, '2022-02-20 04:00:00': 92, '2022-02-20 05:00:00': 77, '2022-02-20 06:00:00': 79, '2022-02-20 07:00:00': 77, '2022-02-20 08:00:00': 112, '2022-02-20 09:00:00': 134, '2022-02-20 10:00:00': 164, '2022-02-20 11:00:00': 173, '2022-02-20 12:00:00': 124, '2022-02-20 13:00:00': 144, '2022-02-20 14:00:00': 154, '2022-02-20 15:00:00': 95, '2022-02-20 16:00:00': 88, '2022-02-20 17:00:00': 71, '2022-02-20 18:00:00': 89, '2022-02-20 19:00:00': 45, '2022-02-20 20:00:00': 39, '2022-02-20 21:00:00': 32, '2022-02-20 22:00:00': 46, '2022-02-20 23:00:00': 73, '2022-02-21 00:00:00': 65, '2022-02-21 01:00:00': 72, '2022-02-21 02:00:00': 65, '2022-02-21 03:00:00': 92, '2022-02-21 04:00:00': 124, '2022-02-21 05:00:00': 147, '2022-02-21 06:00:00': 159, '2022-02-21 07:00:00': 136, '2022-02-21 08:00:00': 161, '2022-02-21 09:00:00': 159, '2022-02-21 10:00:00': 108, '2022-02-21 11:00:00': 141, '2022-02-21 12:00:00': 143, '2022-02-21 13:00:00': 126, '2022-02-21 14:00:00': 96, '2022-02-21 15:00:00': 109, '2022-02-21 16:00:00': 139, '2022-02-21 17:00:00': 150, '2022-02-21 18:00:00': 81, '2022-02-21 19:00:00': 21, '2022-02-21 20:00:00': 0, '2022-02-21 21:00:00': 0, '2022-02-21 22:00:00': 0, '2022-02-21 23:00:00': 0}}}, 'legend_size': 1, 'computed_at': '2022-02-22T03:29:41.928367+00:00'}]
```

but it is not working for data_iter(even changed to data point).getting errors like

```
 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I have to fetch the data and store that into pandas.Any way to export the data from Mixpanel and store that to pandas or iterate in python?